# Liquibase : how to update changelog?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, liquibase, changelog

I am working on a WordPress project, which used Mysql. I need to have DB versioning in the project and I am planning to proceed with Liquibase. I need to backup table schema as well as table contents.

For that, I created changelog file with the schema:
`liquibase --changeLogFile="changelog.xml" generateChangeLog`

Then, I created changelog file with the row contents:
`liquibase --changeLogFile="changelog.xml" --diffTypes=data generateChangeLog`

I  tried updating new DB with above changelog files and I got a replica of the original DB, along with the databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock tables.
But how will I get the changes I made in the DB? I ran `generateChangeLog`  command again, but it created changelog file with full contents.

Does anyone know Liquibase well? That would be a help.

Comment: Hi, @NeenuChandran, did you find a solution to your problem?